# Problems with java and eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have problem when I open eclipse new `Java` project or do anything `Eclipse` close, I have Java `jdk1.7.0_51`, `Eclipse Kepler` and `Windows7 professional`

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

```
 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000007b8, pid=5396, tid=5544
 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b13) (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
 Problematic frame:
 C  0x000007b8
 Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows.    
 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
 The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

Help me please?

Comment: did you try restarting your system?

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be an error from the User Account Control.

The java team is working on this : http://www.java.com/en/download/help/exception_access.xml

hope this may help!